# How do I display a webpage body text only in a web browser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to open a webbrowser control that points to a sharepoint page, but I need to strip out the masterpage and all the visual garbage and just display the body text. I'm kind of inexperienced with winforms, and I'm wondering how to do this. Is there a way to just display the body DOM element in the browser control

UPDATE:
I attempted to downloaded the full body text (with hopes of just substringing the body section), but I'm getting server errors "401 Unauthorized". I did set the credentials of the WebClient object to the appropriate username and password but still same error.

I also tried to snag the raw HTML from the WebBrowser control, but despite the fact that it WILL .navigate() successfully, if I try to access any of the control's properties, it says the WebBrowser control is not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it cannot be done by using standard webbrouser control. You need manually parse html document and create a page that you want to see. Alternative option is to request necessary information from sharepoint web services and display it in a proper way.

Please look at [SharePoint 2010 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx) and [Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model with the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx). Second option is preferable.

Comment: I tried pulling the html from the brower control, but despite the fact that the browser control will navigate, when I try to access the browser object, i keep getting null references. Otherwise, do you have any resources of how I would go about requesting it directly from sharepoint?